# Long young(ParNew) GC pauses

Tags: java, garbage-collection

In one of our application, we are getting long young GC pauses (1-2 seconds long). What could be the reason for such big GC pause? Full GC pauses are under 400ms. Following is the snipped of GC.log for one of the long young GC pause. Java version is Java8. Using CMS Collection. Max heap size is 14G and new generation size is 3GB.

```
2021-06-03T15:06:20.816+0300: 52799589.155: [ParNew
Desired survivor size 536870912 bytes, new threshold 8 (max 8)
- age   1:   68336720 bytes,   68336720 total
: 1959054K->652397K(2097152K), 2.9693698 secs] 7431291K->6950752K(13631488K)After GC:
Statistics for BinaryTreeDictionary:
------------------------------------
Total Free Space: 543441923
Max   Chunk Size: 200036912
Number of Blocks: 150824
Av.  Block  Size: 3603
Tree      Height: 47
, 2.9720357 secs] [Times: user=5.56 sys=0.00, real=2.97 secs]
Heap after GC invocations=1150824 (full 1366):
 par new generation   total 2097152K, used 652397K [0x0000000440000000, 0x0000000500000000, 0x0000000500000000)
  eden space 1048576K,   0% used [0x0000000440000000, 0x0000000440000000, 0x0000000480000000)
  from space 1048576K,  62% used [0x0000000480000000, 0x00000004a7d1b5f0, 0x00000004c0000000)
  to   space 1048576K,   0% used [0x00000004c0000000, 0x00000004c0000000, 0x0000000500000000)
 concurrent mark-sweep generation total 11534336K, used 6298355K [0x0000000500000000, 0x00000007c0000000, 0x00000007c0000000)
 Metaspace       used 50511K, capacity 52221K, committed 52600K, reserved 1095680K
  class space    used 6106K, capacity 6483K, committed 6552K, reserved 1048576K
}
```

Comment: what gc? what java version? what gc arguments?

Comment: Updated question with information

Comment: `CMS` is done, no one supports it, [and it was removed](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/363). You will very unlikely get any good advice.